# How to create your own callback for Ibatis SqlTemplateClientMap

Tags: java, sql, mysql, ibatis, mybatis

I'd like to know how to create my own callback for  a `SqlMapClientTemplate`. Specifically so I can do batch calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I do it is to override the  `SqlMapClientCallback<T>` method `doInSqlMapClient`.

```
   SqlMapClientCallback<Integer> callback = new SqlMapClientCallback<Integer>() {
        public Integer doInSqlMapClient(SqlMapExecutor executor) throws SQLException {
            executor.startBatch();
            //... do your queries here
            return executor.executeBatch();
        }
    };
```

Comment: Thanks! that works! Do you know if there is anything in the API that lets you do this with out overriding that method?

Comment: I actually don't, and I didn't see anything when I looked for it.

Comment: SqlMapClientCallback is an interface, so you have to provide an implementation. SqlMapClientTemplate.execute(SqlMapClientCallback) is the preferred way to call multiple iBatis methods in a single DAO call. This also makes it easier to ensure everything happens in a single transaction.